# Read Throttle Position Sensor and Display the % of Throttle Used

Tags: arduino, automotive

In a previous [post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/83465/throttle-position-sensor-singals/83473#83473) in the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair section, I was able to read two signals from my electronic throttle position sensor in my car. I would like to read these values and record/display the % of throttle being used. I think only one of the two signals is necessary since they both indicate the same thing. These are the range of the two signals:

- Singal 1 (APP 1): Pin 2 and 6, Signal range measured(0.31 V no
  accelerator pushed - 1.74 V accelerator pushed all the way down)
- Signal 2 (APP 2): Pin 2 and 5, Signal range measured(0.62 V no
  accelerator pushed - 3.42 V accelerator pushed all the way down)

My questions are:

- Is analogRead() good for reading this range?
- In order to read the values do I need to connect the GND of Arduino to the GND of the 12v car battery and the two positive cables of the two signals to Arduino's analogs ports?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `analogRead()` is the right approach.

Yes, connect Arduino GND to car chassis.

If you're Arduino can accept 0 - 5 V on the analog inputs then Signal 2 will give you double the resolution as it is twice the voltage.